# Problem with Converting from photo to PDF

Tags: java, itext, converters

I have a problem with converting from png/jpg to pdf ... Everytime I try to convert it the pdf document doesnt take the full size of the png/jpg photo like the photo below.. and this is my converting  code.. I am using itextpdf lib.[image: This is not the original size of my photo]

```java
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\AFKO Fatura\\fatura.pdf"));
document.open();
Image image2 = Image.getInstance("C:\\AFKO FATURA\\fatura.jpg");
document.add(image2);
document.close();`
```

Comment: and this is not the original size of my photo

Comment: Your title talks about converting a photo to png - did you mean pdf instead? I suspect so - please edit the question.

Comment: I suspect you want to use methods on the `Image` such as `scale` and `scaleToFit` though. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: @JonSkeet OH this is my bad I ment to say pdf

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried this but still same problem.

Image image = Image.getInstance ("C:\\AFKO Fatura\\fatura.jpg");
        image.scaleAbsolute(1280f, 960f); //image width,height
        document.open();
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
        file.close();

Comment: I did not know about scaleToFit and I tried it and it worked .... thank you so much @JonSkeet